# Package to find synonyms of english words for Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, nltk, synonym

do you know a package to find synonyms of english words for the Dart language?

For example something similar to NLTK for python it would be perfect.

hope someone can help me
Thank you :)

---

I write these words at random otherwise it won't make me postI write these words at random otherwise it won't make me postI write these words at random otherwise it won't make me postI write these words at random otherwise it won't make me post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research the following packages popped up:

[Lemmatizer](https://pub.dev/packages/lemmatizer)

> Lemmatizer for text in English. Inspired by Python's nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.morphy

Sadly it doesn't support null safety.

[Stemmer](https://pub.dev/packages/stemmer).

> This package implements a stemming algorithm in Dart. Currently, it supports PorterStemmer and SnowballStemmer. It is a port of the exceptional Python NLTK library.

[oxford_dictionary](https://pub.dev/packages/oxford_dictionary) - you would need api key, so based on that I think it is a paid service.

> The Oxford Dictionaries API offers an easy way to access powerful lexical data (words, definitions, translations, audio pronunciations, synonyms, antonyms, parts of speech, and more) to use in your apps and websites.

And if you are not in a hurry: the [Chaquopy Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) is planning to support NLTK library in the future. As it says in the description - it is only available in Android.

> This is a chaquopy plugin to run python code on android. This is the simplest version, where you can write you code and run it.

I don't know if these packages will do the work, but they could be starting point.

**Edit**:
As @Dabbel mentioned in his comment:

[Lemmatizerx](https://pub.dev/packages/lemmatizer)

> Lemmatizer for text in English. Inspired by Python's nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.morphy.

Comment: There is an alternative (and working) `Lemmatizer` package: https://pub.dev/packages/lemmatizerx

Comment: Ok, thanks @Dabbel I will edit my answer to include it. By the time it was written this package didn't exist.

Comment: An unknown benefactor also provided a `dictionary` package https://pub.dev/packages/dictionaryx